# Reduce voltage from 12V to 3.7V/5.4A

Tags: batteries, current, voltage-regulator

my problem is that I have laser (green one) 20W, 3.7V and I want to power it by a car battery that is 12V. I need 3.7V and 5.4A to make it switch on. Do I need a circuit to do it or there is already made device? Thank you!

Comment: You probably want a constant current for your laser, so you would need a switching current source to power the diode. You might be able to find something off the shelf, which is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would use a switching Step Down DC/DC converter.  There are many available.  Search for a Buck converter.  Places like Digikey, Amazon and eBay will definitely have them.  They are available as a voltage or current source.  
If a current source is needed, then the voltage just needs to be higher than 3.7V and be spec'd to have a minimum a output voltage of 3.7 or less.

### UPDATE

I took a look at Digikey and they had nothing with 12 volt input, 3.7V out and 5.6A or greater.  so I was thinking it would be impossible to find an off teh shelf solution.  Then I search Amazon and this comes up:
[DC 24V to 12V CC CV Step Down Volts Regulator Constant Current/Voltage 8A Adjustable Buck Converter 7-40V To 1.2-35V LED Driver Charger Module with Charging Indicator Solar Power Supply DIY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HHQ0VP4)

and

[DC-DC Step-down Constant Current & Voltage Converter 4-38V to 1.25-36V 12V/24V Buck Voltage Regulator 5A 75W High Power LED Constant Current Driver Module for Lithium Battery Electromobile Charging](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VUHVX6W)

Comment: Added an update.